# Proper resolution for icons in Windows

Tags: icon, resolution

I'm making a Java-based program for Windows 7 and I want my application to have a nice logo in the taskbar of windows. I have made a nice logo (in my opinion) but it´s hard to tell what it´s supposed to be once I run the program.

Feels like I´ve tried every possible resolution, nothing looks good. Is there a basic hint or tips that I should know about?

Right know im using `2048X2048` but everything looks like a blobb.

Any ide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eek. 2048x2048 is huge. [This MS article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511280.aspx) says that the maximum size is 256 x 256. I think your problem is the "too much manure for the bag" issue - there's *too much* information in your icon file.

I would suggest starting with something that's 256x256 (possibly scale your icon down to that size as a starting point); you'll be able to see where detail is being lost. One of the trickiest parts of designing an icon is making it recognizable at small scales. Think along the lines of traffic signs - the graphics need to be simple enough to be recognized at 60 mph in less than a second.

Comment: great! Thanks for the suggestion! will upvote when i can.